# Implementing Chat with us functionality in my Ruby on Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, livechat

I want to implement chat with functionality for my website. Not chat application which allows chatting among the users. User can chat to the website only. Exactly like Amcat livechat. How do I achieve this? Any suggestions please. I have googled a lot. But got only ideas and tutorials for chat application only.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to find an off-the-shelf solution that provides some kind of widget that you drop in to your site. Building this kind of thing yourself is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Can u please explain? I want something like live chat in [amcat](https://www.myamcat.com/)

Comment: @kelvin sure. Find a company that provides this livechat service already. A Google search should return plenty of results. Usually the way these services work is by giving you some javascript that you plug in to your site, similar to how Google Analytics works (that's what I mean by a "widget").

Comment: @kelvin you really want to avoid implementing your own livechat system. Running a chat system (or anything real-time) is a non-trivial effort and you're probably better served by working on the great features of your website rather than your kill chat support function.

Comment: For instance, here are two links: https://blog.crazyegg.com/2013/08/05/7-live-chat-software-solutions/ and https://www.clickdesk.com/developer-api

Comment: Thank you. I will try as u suggested.

Comment: @kelvin Best of luck!